# WPF User Control does not honor grid proportional width "*" when used in list view

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have created a simple `UserControl` that has a `Grid` with column widths set to proportional spacing.

```
<UserControl {Usual UC definition stuff}>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=RotOrder}" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Rot1}" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Rot2}" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Rot3}" Grid.Column="3"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

When I use the user control standalone on my window, the proportional spacing is honored even when the control is set to a fixed width and the contents exceed the space available in each `TextBox`.  Any content that doesn't fit is simply left out.

I also tried using the control inside a `ListView`.  I've set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property of the `ListViewItem` to "Stretch" which ensures that all items are the same width.

```
    <ListView Name="MyList2" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
             <local:UserControl1/>   
            </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

As long as the contents of the textboxes fit within the box, the control works like charm with the spacing exactly as expected.  But if the content doesn't fit, the `TextBox` with too much content starts expanding and messing up the proportions.  Is there a reason why the column width proportions are not being honored in this scenario?

Comment: If you are seeing different widths for a column in different rows, that's expected behaviour, as each `ListViewItem` gets its own `Grid` that performs it's own measure and arrange. If you want to have same column widths across rows, then you probably need to use fixed widths.

Comment: The different widths in different rows for the whole control used by the `ListViewItem` is taken care off by the `HorizontalContentAlighment`.  My issue is internal to any one row.  IF I understand `*` terminology correctly, in my example the first column should be the same size as the other 3 columns combined. Always.  The stand-alone control works this way.  If content in a column is too much, it gets chopped off, but the column widths never change.  When in the `ListViewItem` if content in a column gets too big, that column expands and the relative proportions are broken.